# Rotation along fixed point on drag

Tags: javascript, html, drag, kineticjs

Is it possible to rotate a particular shape along fixed point with mousedrag in html5 with javascript and kinecticjs library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the object draggable, and set a dragBoundFunc. i.e., http://jsfiddle.net/bighostkim/7Q5Hd/

```
dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
    var pos = stage.getMousePosition();
    var xd = this.getX() - pos.x ; 
    var yd = this.getY() - pos.y ; 
    var radian = Math.atan2(yd, xd);
    this.setRotation(degree);

    return {
        x: this.getX(),
        y: this.getY()
    }
}
```

Comment: @bighostkim : can u tell me how i can i access the  x and y in the return statement in the function?? i want to store the final vertex points of the rectangle when it stops after rotation. thanks

Comment: x and y does not change. When you drag, it just rotate, which means rotation degree changes not x and y.

Comment: yes x and y doesn't change, i want the other points of shape which get displaced after rotation.